# Hazelcast store all being called for each collection key

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast 3.2.3 (peer to peer mode - but testing on one node for now).

I have attached the following store load implementation to a map via the XML config file:

```
 <map-store enabled="true">
    <class-name>test.TestStoreLoadImpl</class-name>
    <write-delay-seconds>0</write-delay-seconds>
</map-store>
```

However, when the store load gets invoked, it appears that the load all gets called for each value in the collection of keys received i.e. if the collection has 5 Integers, the load all gets called 5 times (instead of being called once and then I should iterate through the collection to fetch the appropriate values, add them to a hashmap and return that).  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
//public class TestStoreLoad implements MapStore<Integer, Test>, MapLoader<Integer, Test>,  MapLoaderLifecycleSupport { 
public class TestStoreLoad implements MapStore<Integer, Test>, MapLoader<Integer, Test> {


//returns 5 keys in one collection
    @Override
    public Set<Integer> loadAllKeys() 

//however the load all gets called 5 times instead of 1
    @Override
    public Map<Integer, Test> loadAll(Collection<Integer> keys) {
        Logger.info("load all called");
```

This seems to be causing issues for me when I use a DB connection from a pool (without any delays).  Now I need to either significantly increase the connection pool size or introduce a time delay in my store load since my connection pool is unable to handle the number of connection requests (I am releasing the connection back to the pool once I am done with an operation in store load).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the default behavior in v3+ - in v2+, it seems like the load all would only get invoked once.  I have not seen any evidence that points otherwise.  Unless I am wrong, one has to make sure this does not cause any issues